# Java vertical line behind text? Like the line in an editor that indates where a page ends

Tags: java, swing

I currently have a program that goes through a code file, and aligns all the comments to the right (100 characters) so they are all in a column and outputs the code in a JList (so each line of the code is an item in the list). What i am trying to do is add a vertical line in the background where all the comments start (similar to the line in netbeans indicating where a page ends) when the adjusted code is outputted. I have a feeling this isnt possible using a JList, can anyone confirm that for sure? Is this possible at all in java, and if so how should i go about doing it?

Comment: Perhaps if you use a `JLayeredPane` with the `JList` at the bottom and the line in a layer above the `JList`

Comment: thanks i hadnt heard of JLayeredPane before

Comment: you could override the paintComponent method of JList.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`javax.swing.BorderFactory.createMatteBorder()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html#createMatteBorder%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Color%29) on the enclosing panel; use a non-zero value for the right side.

```
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 0, 1, Color.red));
```

Comment: Are those [parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html#createMatteBorder%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Color%29) a little off?

Answer (score 1):

Try to play with ListUI to draw a line in background:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog();

    JList list = new JList();
    list.setUI(new LinedListUI());

    dialog.add(new JScrollPane(list));


    dialog.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    dialog.pack();
    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
}


static class LinedListUI extends BasicListUI {

    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {

        super.paint(g, c);
        g.setColor(Color.gray);
        int x = (int) (c.getWidth() * 0.8);
        g.drawLine(x, 0, x, c.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: great answer, much better than the makeshift solution i put together, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're doing, but it seems to me like you could get a decent solution by adding an element in your JList that looks something like "-------------------" where a page break would be so that it displays.  I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for though.

Comment: i think he wants vertical, not horizontal, line... otherwise that would be a solution

Comment: yeah the line has to be vertical, plus id prefer to not actually edit the text like that, because once the comments are realigned the code is going to be saved. The line i am trying to display is purely to make the output of my program look better/make it easier to see if all the comments are aligned properly

Answer (score 0):

Add the lines as html.
Below I have used apache commons StringEscapeUtils.

```
final String COMMENT_BEGIN =
    "<span style='width: 3px; background-color: #00cc00'></span>";
line = "<html>" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(line)
    .replaceFirst("//", COMMENT_BEGIN + "$0");
```

In the same way you could simply make the comment green or so.